# Camel XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, apache-camel, xslt-1.0, transform, xslt-2.0

I am trying to use the XSLT component to do dynamic transformation from XML. Is it possible to pass in a java variable in the URI as XSLT template?
For example:

```
from("direct:foo").
  to("xslt:${fee}").
  to("direct:output");
```

foo - is a XML payload, 
  fee - XSLT template stored as java.lang.String, 
  output - xml payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Camel does not have support for dynamic XSLT input stream, I had to create my own Transformer. This might help someone

Here is my code snippet. I used camel processor as below

```
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        Target target = xmlMapper.readValue(transform(getInputStreamFromDocument(xmlPayload), new ByteArrayInputStream(xsltTemplate.getBytes())), target.class);
    }


    public byte[] transform(InputStream dataXML, InputStream inputXSL)
            throws TransformerException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(inputXSL));
        StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(bos);
        transformer.transform(in, out);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: how do you invoke this in camel?

Comment: Updated above. Using a camel processor/bean you can invoke it

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your variable into message header by some conditions:

```
.setHeader("TemplateLocation").constant("OSGI-INF/xsl/pretty.xsl")
```

After, you can use **Recipient List** EIP:

```
.recipientList().simple("xslt:${header.TemplateLocation}")
```

or you can use *toD*:

```
.toD("xslt:${header.TemplateLocation}")
```

Working example:

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                    .routeId("xsltTest")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "XML input : \n${body}")
            .setHeader("TemplateLocation").constant("OSGI-INF/xsl/pretty.xsl")
            //.recipientList().simple("xslt:${header.TemplateLocation}")
            .toD("xslt:${header.TemplateLocation}")
            .to("log:end?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true");
        }
    };
}
```

And there is no way to use a string variable as an xslt template, as far as I know.

Comment: I do not have a static template like "OSGI-INF/xsl/pretty.xs'. I will be getting pretty.xs payload in request and pass that for transformation.

Comment: Maybe you could save the xlst template to an external file and then assing its name into message header as shown above. Also possible would be a useful  _contentCache=false_ option.

Comment: In a multi-threading env If I create XSL file for every request, Its going to be a mess. I do not want to do that. Is there any clear way of passing the request body to the XSLT component?

Comment: Nothing like what you need in the documentation. Only if you develop your own processor, for example. Use standard Java tools inside it (TransformerFactory, StreamSource ). Pass a xslt template in the message body or in the header or use the content enricher EIP to load the template into your own processor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge

- Your XSLT poller has a dynamic expression as subdirectory (${fee}).
  As far as I know you cannot have a dynamic from address in a Camel
  route. Because this would mean that you could consume from multiple
  endpoints.

You can have it as separate file and call it like this 
 **to("xslt:file:///foo/bar.xsl").**

For more details [XSLT](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/xslt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot use a dynamic stylesheet** (dynamic content) with the XSL component of Camel.

The most dynamic thing you can do is a **dynamic reference to a static file** like this:

```
.toD("xslt:${expressionWithFileReference}")
```

However, you can simply **call a Java bean** to do what you want and call it from the route:

```
.bean(javaBeanReference or new YourJavaBean())
```

In the Bean you can use [Camel annotations](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html) to inject header(s), properties and the body into a method. Whatever you need from the current Camel Exchange.

```
public void yourMethod(
    @Header(headername) String parameterName, 
    @Body Type parameterName) {
...
}
```